# problem with properties which determine the method to call on wire:click buttons

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-livewire-wireclick

I have a problem with liveware, which is that I cannot make dynamic buttons whose method depends on the model, for example:
[each button depends on the array returned by the Vote model, which defer according to 'type' of this vote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ia18.png)
the problem starts after clicking on an action that changes the 'type' of vote, then the list of buttons changes (also the methods name in wire:click).

But I hope someone help me find a clever way to do it, this solution is not so much useful when things get complicated!

[I used to create a hidden button to load js code for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOBMl.png)

Comment: Please don't attach images, publish your code as text. I made a quick test and the dynamic rendering of the buttons/actions works perfectly for me.

Comment: Have you tried `wire:key`

Comment: You can try to not make decision of method name in blade, but always call one Livewire method (callMethod()), and pass parameter of submethod, and the logic would be inside Livewire

Comment: thank you all for helping, indeed, @Autista_z, I used only one methode name in the blade to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you shoud add `wire:key` like in example

```
<div>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div wire:key="{{ $post->id }}"> 
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

The [documenatation](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/components#adding-wirekey-to-foreach-loops) shoudl be very usefull.